# PyCharm does not find function, but spyder does

Tags: python, pycharm, spyder

I used to use Spyder for my projects and now switch to PyCharm. I navigate to the folder `myfolder` both in Spyder and Pycharm and run:

```
from tools.PATHS import ICG_PATH, DEV_PATH
```

where tools is a folder in `myfolder` and `PATHS` is a `.py` file containing `ICG_PATH, DEV_PATH`.

This works fine in Spyder, PyCharm throws:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools'
```

Comment: In pycharm mark the directory as `source root`, right-click on the project directory, and select `mark directory as` option.

Comment: @R__raki__ `myfolder` should be marked as source root right?